# Kotlin Sequence to Array

Tags: arrays, kotlin, stream, escaping, java-stream

How to efficiently convert a `Sequence` to an `Array` (or a primitive array, like `IntArray`) in Kotlin?

I found that there are no `toArray()` methods for `Sequence`s. And `toList().toArray()` (`toList().toIntArray()`) creates an extra temporary list.

Comment: toList().toArray() not working for you?

Comment: I am dealing with very large data (something that takes hundreds of gigabytes of memory) and I don't want to add extra space and time overhead.

Comment: I created an issue for this problem: [To array extension functions with a size parameter for Sequences and Iterables : KT-31260](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31260)

Comment: I've added additional example at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31260#focus=streamItem-27-3716001.0-0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no `toArray()` methods because, unlike a list, a sequence does not allow to find out how many elements it contains (and it can actually be infinite), so it's not possible to allocate an array of the correct size.

If you know something about the sequence in your specific case, you can write a more efficient implementation by allocating an array and copying the elements from the sequence to the array manually. For example, if the size is known, the following function can be used:

```
fun Sequence<Int>.toIntArray(size: Int): IntArray {
    val iter = iterator()
    return IntArray(size) { iter.next() }
}
```

Comment: Suppose that I know the size, is there a simple extension method, something like `toArray(size: Int)` (`toIntArray(size: Int)`), to "allocate an array and copy the elements from the sequence to the array "?

Comment: Or at least is there a simpler functional way than doing it "manually"?

Comment: `Sequence<T>` does have `toList()` though, which also requires knowing the number of elements, so the reasoning in the first paragraph is questionable. It seems like they could have just added `toArray()` alongside.

Comment: @Hakanai Which list type are you referring to? Most implementations of the `List` interface don't require you to know the number of elements up front. In particular, `ArrayList` starts with a capacity but grows as needed. `LinkedList` doesn't even care at all. Arrays simply cannot be constructed without a size. A hypothetical `toArray` could create an array of arbitrary size and then allocate new (bigger) arrays as needed when iterating the sequence, but that would be reimplementing `ArrayList` - and I don't see the point of that. However a `toArray(size: Int)` might be useful to some people

Comment: @Joffrey I don't follow this argument. They could implement it _using_ `ArrayList`. They could implement it as `toList().toXArray()` even. The point is, Kotlin's `Sequence<T>` doesn't have a method to convert to an array, while Java's `Stream<T>` does. It's a hole in Kotlin's API which presumably will be filled at some point, but right now it is a glaring omission.

Comment: @Hakanai This is a fair point, though I believe that most of the time, people that would see a `toArray()` method would expect it *not* to go through a list, otherwise they may as well just use the list themselves. Arrays are just less convenient to use in general, and are less prevalent in Kotlin unless you have specific performance needs, and then in that case using `toArray` implemented with `ArrayList` would be pretty bad anyway. So I think there is little benefit in adding such an API (especially because it would be misleading users into believing it collects right into an array)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a version for `Sequence<T>`. Using the refied T (which requires the function to be inline) to create an array of the correct type, which would not be posible in Java :D

```
inline fun <reified T> Sequence<T>.toArray(size: Int): Array<T> {
  val iter = iterator()
  return Array(size) { iter.next() }
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with you on this, as `Array<T>` creates an inefficient object array instead of a primitive array.

Answer (score 0):

Because I can not write a comment, it's another version of the highest answer for primitive type.

```kotlin
fun <I, O> Sequence<I>.toArray(
    size: Int,
    factory: (size: Int, init: (Int) -> I) -> O
): O {
    val iter = iterator()
    return factory(size) { iter.next() }
}

//usage
seq<Byte>
  .toArray(size, ::ByteArray)
```